# Accessing table data created through manytomanyfield in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have this model file in which a user can own any number of farms and admin can create a charge and put it on one or many farms.The problem is that i want to access the table created through ManyToManyField in **Charges** model.I want to select only those rows of manytomanyfield that are related to a single user.

suppose if admin created a charge with id ***"3383"*** and selected five farms from MultiSelectWidget.In those five farms a user name "Mike" has two farms.ManyToManyField table will create 5 rows for in its table including 2 rows for user "Mike" farms .I want to access to those 2 rows but could not manage to get to those two rows.

***Note:*** I just have the user id with me for look up

**Models.py**

```
class Farm(models.Model):
    farmNo = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class FarmOwner(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    farm = models.ManyToManyField(Farm)

class Charges(models.Model):
    chargeId = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    farms = models.ManyToManyField(Farm)
```

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that the charge Id is `3383` and that the user is `mike` you can get those 2 related rows by using this

```
mikes_farm_list = FarmOwner.Objects.filter(owner="Mike").values_list('farms', flat=True)
Charges.Objects.filter(chargeId=3383, farms__in=mikes_farm_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mike = Farm.objects.get(farmNo="Mike")
for charge in mike.charge_set.all():
    print charge.chargeId
```

Check out the model field docs for a many to many.  you can change the attribute name of "charge_set" to something else ("charges") by putting a related_name="charges" in your Charge model M2M declaration.